# Programmatically disable Taskmanager (ctrl+alt+del )

Tags: c#, registry, taskmanager, group-policy

I am currently developing an application to configure Win10 IoT machines more easily.
Imagine an user on a maching having a custom shell and pretty much all predefined shortcuts disabled so he can only work with the production application.
In order to switch users and configure the system however, "Win+L" has to stay enabled.
Now in the "Win+L" screen that comes up he will still find the option to get into Taskmanager (what is not desired).
What the admin can to to prevent this is use gpedit and change the ctrl+alt+del options on the machine.
This is exactly what I want to do.

[Programmatically disabling Taskmanager using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971097/programmatically-disabling-taskmanager-using-c-sharp#)

Is pretty close, **but this registry entry only works for the currently logged on user** which in my case is the administrator as the configuration tool needs administrative priviledges (UWF Filter etc. can be configured).

If I try the same in LocalMachine rather than CurrentUser, the registryentry is created as expected but it has no effect at all.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically disabling Taskmanager using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971097/programmatically-disabling-taskmanager-using-c-sharp)

Comment: You can load another user's registry hive using `reg load`, or various winapi methods

Comment: @Absinthe I don't think it is - that question talks about how to disable task manager for the *current* user, not for a different user.

Comment: @Absinthe, I posted the exact same link with explanation why it is not exactly what I need.

Comment: @canton7 do you have something to read for me or even an example? Sounds like a good option.

Comment: @christian nothing specific, only the google hits for `reg load` and `load registry hive C#`

Comment: Have you looked into Windows Kiosk Mode?

Comment: I am using UWF and WMI to set up a kiosk mode.
Every user can have a custom application running instead of explorer.exe.
You can disable shortcuts systemwide and protect/ unprotect volumes.
Thus it would be great if you can suppress the taskmanager for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what I wanted:

```
public void SetTaskManager(bool enable)
    {
      // Load settings of desired user via UserName property
      using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
      {
        var command = Properties.Settings.Default.LoadRegistryOfUser;
        command = command.Replace("USERNAME", UserName);
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(command);
        var res = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
      }

      // Create the key and entry for the registry or delete it if
      // enable == true
      RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.Users.CreateSubKey(
         UserName + @"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
      if (enable && objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") != null)
        objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
      else
        objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);

      objRegistryKey.Close();

      // Close the registry of the user, otherwise he cant log on
      using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
      {
        var command = Properties.Settings.Default.CloseRegistryOfUser;
        command = command.Replace("USERNAME", UserName);
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript(command);
        var res = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
      }
    }
```

Skripts:

LoadRegistryOfUser:
reg load HKU\USERNAME C:\users\USERNAME\NTUSER.DAT

CloseRegistryOfUser:
reg unload HKU\USERNAME

Its a bit hacky but the only way I found so far.
Hope this helps.